# what will be the output of the following verilog code..?

Tags: verilog

```
module abc(input clk, output a);
reg a;
always @(posedge clk)
begin
a=0;
$monitor("%d",a);
end

always @(posedge clk)
begin
a=1;
$monitor("%d",a);
end
```

what will be the first output after first clk pulse? if we don't want any default value of reg(we want a value for a)...?

Answer (score 2):

This is a race condition. Verilog does not guarantee the ordering of execution between processes synchronized to the same event. One simulation tool might pick the first block. another tool might pick the second block. Synthesis tools will not allow multiple assignments to the same variable from different blocks.

Comment: imagine there is only 1 block and we want intial value of reg and don't want it to be X. what changes within the code we need to do..??

Comment: That depends on which synthesis tool/target technology you are using. Some tools allow a power-up reset condition by declaring `reg a=0` or `initial a=0`. If you are not synthesizing this, either method will work.